# Does conference presentation of preliminary findings conflict with publication?

Tags: publications, journals, presentation

I am exciting to share our preliminary results. I also want to demonstrate productivity, so I'm wrestling with the idea of presenting findings in presentation and poster format at an upcoming conference. The research is in health care. However, our big journals typically don't publish papers on data that has been published or presented elsewhere. I'm looking for any advice on navigating journal requirements such as:

**Resuscitation:**

> The paper should deal with original material, neither
>   previously published nor being considered for publication elsewhere,
>   except in special circumstances agreed with the Editor-in-Chief.

**Annals of Emergency Medicine:**

> Annals publishes only original work in
>   accordance with the ICMJE policy on overlapping publications. If your
>   manuscript or data, in whole or part, has been published elsewhere, or
>   has been or will be submitted for publication elsewhere, this may
>   constitute unacceptable prior and/or duplicate publication. Should
>   there be any doubt, please detail the specific circumstances to us in
>   your cover letter. Failure to do so could be interpreted as deliberate
>   duplicate publication.

What would people think if we published secondary outcomes and answered a different research question than the research manuscript we intend to ultimately publish? Thoughts?

Comment: What's stopping you from asking if you can present preliminary findings at a conference with the caveat that it is currently under peer review at publication X?

Comment: I don’t see anything in the journal policies you quote forbidfing submission of material _presented_ elsewhere; apparently, only prior _publication_ is forbidden. Posters are not generally considered publications, are they?

Comment: I think you're both right. I can disclose that it is under review elsewhere, thanks Frank FYC. And regarding the poster, I think I just have to confirm that the poster abstract is not going to be published in the journal associated with the conference. This is helpful feedback, thank you JeffE.

Answer (score 2):

To codify the comments: These policies say nothing about presentations, only publications.  As conferences are not journals, it's highly unlikely that this *is* double-dipping.